# How do you bin a dataset and start the bins from 0?

Tags: python, numpy, histogram, bin

I have a dataset where I have observations at arange of depths in the sea. I am trying to plot the frequency on the x-axis and the depth on the y-axis of a histogram.

#
This section is sorted
In order to do this, I wanted to bin the data for every 5 metre category. The only problem is, the depths in the dataset start at 2m, but I want the bins to start at 0m, and increase in 5m intervals. I don't know how to set the bins to start at 0m.
#

In addition, I'm plotting a histogram to show this, and I would like the depth to be on the y-axis (so that the plot is a bit more intuitive to look at)

Currently I have code that sorts the data into bins (I don't know the size) and then plots a histogram, but with the depth on the x-axis. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
#Data read in at this point  

depthout = []
Dout = np.array(depthout)



bins = np.linspace(0,260,61)
plt.hist(Dout, bins)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Here is a good starting point: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist

Comment: So, I think I've managed to sort out the bins (which I've updated above, my problem now is that I need the axes to swap so that the bars are horizontal instead of vertical.

Comment: Check the matplotlib gallery, you will find this link: http://matplotlib.org/examples/lines_bars_and_markers/barh_demo.html and for a more sophisticated barchar plot check this link: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/barchart_demo2.html